# Selecting all rows for 3 tables using INNER JOIN in JPQL

Tags: java, sql, jpa, jpql

I have a problem in selecting all rows within 3 tables in JPQL. I want to return it as a `Collection<Object>`.

```
protected Collection<Object> getRecords(){
    emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("MyPersistenceUnit");
    em = emf.createEntityManager();

    em.getTransaction().begin();

    TypedQuery<Object> query = em.createQuery("SELECT * FROM Vehiclehistory As h INNER JOIN Vehicles As v ON h.vehicleID = v.vehicleID INNER JOIN Clients As c ON h.clientID = c.clientID",Object.class);
    Collection<Object> list = query.getResultList();

    em.getTransaction().commit();

    return list;
}
```

The error showing is :

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: An exception occurred while creating  a query in EntityManager: 
Exception Description: Syntax error parsing [SELECT * FROM Vehiclehistory As h INNER JOIN Vehicles As v ON h.vehicleID = v.vehicleID INNER JOIN Clients As c ON h.clientID = c.clientID]. 
[138, 138] A select statement must have a FROM clause.
[7, 7] The left expression is missing from the arithmetic expression.
[9, 138] The right expression is not an arithmetic expression.
```

Is it the query? Should I use createQuery or createNativeQuery? Or Should I use Query only not TypedQuery?

Thank you.

Comment: JPQL is not the same language as SQL. select * is wrong. JOIN Vehicles As v ON h.vehicleID = v.vehicleID is wrong. JPQL uses associations for joins. And a JPQL query select entity alias(es) and/or entity fields.

Comment: I get it now. I should reference first the foreign key fields for me to assign them aliases. thank you for the response

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to this link : [INNER JOIN IN JPQL](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/jpql/from#INNER_JOIN_)

Like for example:

```
SELECT v.[vehicleinfo] FROM Vehiclehistory AS h INNER JOIN h.vehicleID AS v ON h.vehicleID = v.vehicleID
```

> h.vehicleID as v

it only tells that i need to reference first the foreign key from the left table and give it an alias so that i may easily call it and use it in ***ON***

Comment: How would you do multiple inner joins? So inner join to one table, then inner join to another table...